# Sport club or gym

Tags: word-usage

I live in Ukraine and I always come across signboards like "**Sport club**" or
 "**Our sport club is the best**" etc.
Basically those "sport clubs" are gyms.
So i want to know if it's accurate to call gyms like that, is it ok? Do you call them like that, can you say "where are you? Oh I am at the sport club?"

P.S. I know that the adjective of "sport" is " "sports" I am asking you if I can use "sportclub" as a synonym of "gym" ? Thank you!

Comment: Note that ***sports*** *club* is [more common by far](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sport+club%2C+sports+club&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csport%20club%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csports%20club%3B%2Cc0) than ***sport*** *club*.

Answer (score 2):

No, both are not exactly the same.
A [Sports Club](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sports_club) is a place where people play sports. It could be for fitness purposes, or just as a pass time.
Whereas, a [Gym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gym) is where people exercise for fitness purposes. The exercise is not always athletic.

Comment: Yeah - a sports club might well have a gym (but not necessary), but it will likely also have tennis courts, squash courts, swimming pool, basketball court, five-a-side, climbing wall etc - things you wouldn't typically find in a gym (Gym would have weights, cardio-machines, treadmills, other fitness equipment).